# Script to delete all folders it is placed in

Tags: shell, batch-file

Can anyone here help me out with a script that will let me, when run, delete all the folders and their contents in whatever folder it is placed in.

Comment: Do you want to delete where the script exists or where you currently are. IOW, if the script is /bin/x and your current directory is /bob, do you want to delete in /bin or /bob?

Answer (score 5):

What operating system?  Do you want to remove **files** in the current directory also?

Under cmd.exe in Windows, for files, you can run

```
del /s /q *
```

or to remove **just folders** and their contents,

```
for /d %d in (*.*) do rmdir /s /q %d
```

Under most Linux/UNIX shells, to delete **files and folders**, you can run

```
rm -rf *
```

or as pointed out below by derobert (and tidied up a little), you can do **just folders** and their contents with

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name '.' -type d -exec rm -rf \{\} \;
```

This will find all the directories in the current directory (maxdepth 1) excluding the current directory '.', and run rm -rf on each of them.

Comment: Ummm, he asked to delete /folders/ not folders AND FILES.

Comment: ... to be specific, given a folder with a subfolder A and a file B, he asked to delete A (and its contents), but not B.

Comment: The originally-worded question didn't actually spell that out explicitly, or give any detail.  Your approach for that case is great though.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, you can do something like this:

```
find -type d -maxdepth 1 -not -name '.' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -Rf
```

This will get rid of all folders (and their contents) in the current working directory, leaving only the files not inside a folder. Given:

```
test/folder1
test/folder1/file1
test/file2
```

if you run it in `test`, then only file2 will be left.